# Split dataframe and Create multipanel scatterplots from list of data frames

Tags: r, plot

I have a dataframe like so:

```
set.seed(453)

year= as.factor(c(rep("1998", 20), rep("1999", 16)))
lepsp= c(letters[seq(from = 1, to = 20 )], c('a','b','c'),letters[seq(from =8, to = 20 )]) 
freq= c(sample(1:15, 20, replace=T), sample(1:18, 16,replace=T))
df<-data.frame(year, lepsp, freq)

df<- 
  df %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  mutate(rank = dense_rank(-freq))
```

Frequencies `freq` of each `lepsp` within each year are ranked in the `rank` column. Larger `freq` values correspond to the smallest `rank` value and smaller `freq` values have the largest `rank` values. Some rankings are repeated if levels of `lepsp` have the same abundance.

I would like to split the `df` into multiple subsets by year. Then I would like to plot each subsetted dataframe in a multipanel figure.  Essentially this is to create species abundance curves. The x-axis would be `rank` and the yaxis needs to be `freq`.

In my real dataframe I have 22 years of data. I would prefer the graphs to be displayed as 2 columns of 4 rows for a total of 8 graphs per page. Essentially I would have to repeat the solution offered here 3 times.

I also need to demarcate the 25%, 50% and 75% quartiles  with vertical lines to look like this (desired result): 
[image]

It would be great if each graph specified the year to which it belonged, but since all axis are the same name, I do not want x and y labels to be repeated for each graph.

I have tried to plot multiple lines on the same graph but it gets messy.

```
year.vec<-unique(df$year)

plot(sort(df$freq[df$year==year.vec[1]], 
decreasing=TRUE),bg=1,type="b", ylab="Abundance", xlab="Rank", 
pch=21, ylim=c(0, max(df$freq)))

for (i in 2:22){
 points(sort(df$freq[df$year==year.vec[i]], decreasing=TRUE), bg=i, 
 type="b", pch=21)
   }

legend("topright", legend=year.vec, pt.bg=1:22, pch=21)
```

I have also tried a loop, however it does not produce an output and is missing some of the arguments I would like to include:

```
jpeg('pract.jpg')
par(mfrow = c(6, 4))  # 4 rows and 2 columns
for (i in unique(levels(year))) {
    plot(df$rank,df$freq, type="p", main = i)
}
dev.off()
```

**Update**
(Attempted result) 
[image]

I found the following code after my post which gets me a little closer, but is still missing all the features I would like:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
library (ggthemes)
x <- ggplot(data = df2, aes(x = rank, y = rabun)) +
  geom_point(aes(fill = "dodgerblue4")) +
  theme_few() +
  ylab("Abundance") + xlab("Rank") +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = 15),
    axis.title.y = element_text(size = 15),
    axis.text.x = element_text(size = 15),
    axis.text.y = element_text(size = 15),
    plot.title = element_blank(),            # we don't want individual plot titles as the facet "strip" will give us this
    legend.position = "none",                # we don't want a legend either
    panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA, color = "darkgrey", size = 1.25, linetype = "solid"),
    axis.ticks = element_line(colour = 'darkgrey', size = 1.25, linetype = 'solid'))     # here, I just alter to colour and thickness of the plot outline and tick marks. You generally have to do this when faceting, as well as alter the text sizes (= element_text() in theme also)
x
x <- x + facet_wrap( ~ year, ncol = 4)
x
```

I prefer base R to modify graph features, and have not been able to find a method using base R that meets all my criteria above. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the `lepsp` column values don't effect the plot at all. Is this correct? Also, I want to check - do the quartile lines need to be calculated independently for each year? Or do you have the same number of observations per year so they are always in the same place?

Comment: And lastly, how much do you want to use base R? This would be  less than 30 lines of code for `ggplot2`, but probably 100-300 lines of code for base plotting to get it looking nice.

Comment: It won't be 100-300 lines of code in base R.

Comment: That is true- the `lepsp` does not effect the graph. I just wanted to show that for each year subset, some species may be shared between years others not. Also,   if species share the same abundance they will essentially share the same point on the graph. Quartile lines will differ year to year since the `freq` values will vary for each subset. Each year has a different number of observations.

Comment: I am not opposed to ggplot, so if you have a solution using ggplot I will gladly accept. I like the cleanliness of image I posted so the closer I can get it to that the better.  ggplot tends to have a  lot of interesting default settings that, for a novice user like myself, can get lengthly to change so I was weary to go that route. But, if it is easy to make multiple graphs like  the image using ggplot I am all for it. Thank you for your inquiry.

Comment: @Parfait I'd like to be proven otherwise, but my experience with multiplot layouts in base graphics, not repeating x/y labels unnecessarily, getting the spacing right... takes a lot of code.

Comment: @Danielle ... please post screenshot of your current result and not just desired result.

Comment: @Parfait ...hopefully that helps clarify any confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `ggplot` approach. First off, I made some more data to get the 3x2 layout:

```
df = rbind(df, mutate(df, year = year + 4), mutate(df, year = year + 8))
```

Then We do a little manipulation to generate the quantiles and labels by group:

```
df_summ =
    df %>% group_by(year) %>%
    do(as.data.frame(t(quantile(.$rank, probs = c(0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75)))))
names(df_summ)[2:5] = paste0("q", 0:3)

df_summ_long = gather(df_summ, key = "q", value = "value", -year) %>%
    inner_join(data.frame(q = paste0("q", 0:3), lab = c("Common", "Rare-75% -->", "Rare-50% -->", "Rare-25% -->"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
```

With the data in good shape, plotting is fairly simple:

```
library(ggthemes)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = rank, y = freq)) +
    geom_point() +
    theme_few() +
    labs(y = "Abundance (% of total)", x = "Rank") +
    geom_vline(data = df_summ_long[df_summ_long$q != "q0", ], aes(xintercept = value), linetype = 4, size = 0.2) + 
    geom_text(data = df_summ_long, aes(x = value, y = Inf, label = lab), size = 3, vjust = 1.2, hjust = 0) +
    facet_wrap(~ year, ncol = 2)
```

[image]

There's some work left to do - mostly in the rarity text overlapping. It might not be such an issue with your actual data, but if it is you could pull the max y values into `df_summ_long` and stagger them a little bit, actually using `y` coordinates instead of just `Inf` to get it at the top like I did.

Comment: This is wonderful at first glance, thank you so much for investing your time. I will try it on my real data now and will keep in touch if I come across any issues. Thanks again!